# Unable to setup google hangout API

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

I have been reading google developers API document and trying to setup my private hangout chat for employees. I have created project in Console, enabled hangout API, verified domain ownership used for service and all that is listed at step one and two on this page https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started.

When I go to page Run your app privatly on page https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/running#running-private I cant find way to add my app as is mentioned here, because there is no Add apps link.

> Move the mouse pointer to the left edge of the Hangout to reveal the
>   menu, choose the three dots (...), then Add apps. The app picker
>   appears.

Could you please help me